# Convert orgmode to Rmd

Tags: org-babel, r, markdown

As the title says, I have an `orgmode` file I have been using with `ess` and exporting to `TeX` which has been going very well. However, I need to now export to `html` for reasons out of my control, and was wondering if there is a clean way to obtain an `Rmd` file from the `org` file.

Note that this is **not** the same as obtaining a `markdown` file.

To clarify the workflow as requested from the comments. The situation is as follows:

1. I have a set of `orgmode` files which were used to analyze data (via `ess`)
2. Typically I would export these to `hugo-markdown` for `html` output downstream (with `ox-hugo`, e.g. [this file](https://rgoswami.me/posts/sr2-ch13-ch14/)) and `polymode-org-mode` for `TeX` which works great

However, now I **do** need to edit the files in an `.Rmd` setting (hiding code chunks and adding some more analysis). Currently one approach is to export to `markdown` and then copy out what I need, but that seems inefficient. Similarly, the idea of manually messing with my `html` files is also not appealing.

The current issue is that `orgmode` export isn't clean enough to work as an `Rmd` file (though the `pandoc-orgmode` one is close).

The workflow I'm looking for is then:

1. Load an R-session and work in an `orgmode` file
2. Tangle (??) to an `.Rmd` so other people can muck around

I'm not really interested in the inverse route, since I don't really mind working in `Rmd` either (and I can connect to the same R-session), I'd just rather not hand-convert my existing files.

Note that in the current setup, the `orgmode` file has a *lot* of extra `LATEX_HEADER` options, since I was mostly just exporting to `TeX`. These options also mess with the output when working with the standard exporters.

Comment: Can you explain your workflow? It's definitley possible to export org -> html and org -> md. Unless you actually need to edit the Rmd, maybe one of these would work for you?

Comment: Sure, I've added some more context.

Comment: I understand. That would be useful for me as well, as I prefer org mode but have a lot of collaborators that only use RStudio

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Could you provide a link to a sample Org file that causes problems.  I assume you have tried `pandoc` and/or `ox-pandoc`?  If so, what is it exactly that doesn't get translated correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to generate an Rmd file from an org file is to use [ox-ravel](https://github.com/chasberry/orgmode-accessories).

I use it all the time to generate the Rmd and then the html file using `rmarkdown::render`. It is great to share results with non-emacs users. It handles inline images, code, inline tables, you can add interactive images with `plotly`, interactive networks with  `networkviz` etc.

The one thing that I don't like is that it can become very slow in some situations.